Decoding JSON with msgspec into NumPy arrays
I'm trying to utilize msgspec to encode and decode numpy data into json serialized objects. I've found lots of good resources on encoding the data and gotten my encoder to work no problem, but I can't get the data decoded back into the original format.
from dataclasses import dataclass
import numpy as np
import msgspec as ms
from traits.api import List, Array, Instance

def NumpyEncoder(obj):
    if isinstance(
        obj,
        (
            np.int_,
            np.intc,
            np.intp,
            np.int8,
            np.int16,
            np.int32,
            np.int64,
            np.uint8,
            np.uint16,
            np.uint32,
            np.uint64,
        ),
    ):
        return int(obj)
    elif isinstance(obj, (np.float_, np.float16, np.float32, np.float64)):
        return float(obj)
    elif isinstance(obj, (np.ndarray,)):
        return obj.tolist()
    return ms.json.encode(obj)

enc = ms.json.Encoder(enc_hook=NumpyEncoder)

@dataclass
class C:
    c1: np.ndarray = Array(dtype=np.float64)

@dataclass
class A:
    a1: list[C] = List(Instance(C))

c = C(np.ones(10))
a = A(c1 = c)

enc.encode(a)

which gives the correct serialized value of a. But how do I decode it correctly?
I've tried the following:
def NumpyEncoder(obj):
    if isinstance(
        obj,
        (
            np.int_,
            np.intc,
            np.intp,
            np.int8,
            np.int16,
            np.int32,
            np.int64,
            np.uint8,
            np.uint16,
            np.uint32,
            np.uint64,
        ),
    ):
        return int(obj)
    elif isinstance(obj, (np.float_, np.float16, np.float32, np.float64)):
        return float(obj)
    elif isinstance(obj, (np.ndarray,)):
        return dict(__ndarray__=obj.tolist(),dtype=str(obj.dtype))
    return ms.json.encode(obj)

class NumpyDecoder:
    def decoderHook(self, dct):
        """Decodes a previously encoded numpy ndarray with proper shape and 
           dtype.

        :param dct: (dict) json encoded ndarray
        :return: (ndarray) if input was an encoded ndarray
        """
        if isinstance(dct, dict) and '__ndarray__' in dct:
            return np.array(dct["__ndarray__"], dct['dtype'])
        return ms.json.decode(dct)

enc = ms.json.Encoder(enc_hook=NumpyEncoder)
dec = ms.json.Decoder(dec_hook=NumpyDecoder, type=A)

b = enc.encode(a)
print(dec.decode(b))

Which does not decode b back into an object of type A.
Thanks!

As you intend to use dataclass for inheriting purposes, I've added this answer for tackling that, please let me know if this works as well.
import numpy as np
import msgspec
from dataclasses import dataclass, field
from typing import List

# Custom encoder function for numpy objects
def NumpyEncoder(obj):
    if isinstance(
        obj,
        (
            np.int_,
            np.intc,
            np.intp,
            np.int8,
            np.int16,
            np.int32,
            np.int64,
            np.uint8,
            np.uint16,
            np.uint32,
            np.uint64,
        ),
    ):
        return int(obj)
    elif isinstance(obj, (np.float_, np.float16, np.float32, np.float64)):
        return float(obj)
    elif isinstance(obj, (np.ndarray,)):
        return {"__ndarray__": obj.tolist(), "dtype": str(obj.dtype)}
    return ms.json.encode(obj)

# Custom decoder function for numpy objects
def numpy_decoder_hook(type_, dct):
    if isinstance(dct, dict) and "__ndarray__" in dct:
        return np.array(dct["__ndarray__"], dtype=dct["dtype"])
    return dct

# Define data classes
@dataclass
class C:
    c1: np.ndarray

@dataclass
class A:
    a1: List[C] = field(default_factory=list)

# Creating encoder and decoder with hooks
enc = msgspec.json.Encoder(enc_hook=NumpyEncoder)
dec = msgspec.json.Decoder(dec_hook=numpy_decoder_hook, type=A)

# Create instances
c = C(c1=np.ones(10))
a = A(a1=[c])

# Encode
encoded = enc.encode(a)
print(f"Encoded: {encoded}")

# Decode
decoded = dec.decode(encoded)
print(f"Decoded: {decoded}")
print(f"Decoded a1[0].c1: {decoded.a1[0].c1}")


Please check if this solves the issue, I'll add explanation, if it works
import numpy as np
import msgspec
from dataclasses import dataclass
from traits.api import List, Array, Instance

def NumpyEncoder(obj):
    if isinstance(
        obj,
        (
            np.int_,
            np.intc,
            np.intp,
            np.int8,
            np.int16,
            np.int32,
            np.int64,
            np.uint8,
            np.uint16,
            np.uint32,
            np.uint64,
        ),
    ):
        return int(obj)
    elif isinstance(obj, (np.float_, np.float16, np.float32, np.float64)):
        return float(obj)
    elif isinstance(obj, (np.ndarray,)):
        return {"__ndarray__": obj.tolist(), "dtype": str(obj.dtype)}
    return ms.json.encode(obj)

def numpy_decoder_hook(type_, dct):
    if isinstance(dct, dict) and "__ndarray__" in dct:
        return np.array(dct["__ndarray__"], dtype=dct["dtype"])
    return dct

class C(msgspec.Struct):
    c1: np.ndarray

class A(msgspec.Struct):
    a1: list[C]

enc = msgspec.json.Encoder(enc_hook=NumpyEncoder)
dec = msgspec.json.Decoder(dec_hook=numpy_decoder_hook, type=A)

c = C(c1=np.ones(10))
a = A(a1=[c])

encoded = enc.encode(a)
print(f"Encoded: {encoded}")

decoded = dec.decode(encoded)
print(f"Decoded: {decoded}")
print(f"Decoded a1[0].c1: {decoded.a1[0].c1}")


This works, but is there a way to maintain C and A as dataclass classes?

While dataclass is a general-purpose tool, msgspec.Struct is specialized for msgspec serialization. Using dataclass might require additional conversion steps or custom encoders/decoders to ensure the data is serialized correctly, which msgspec.Struct handles inherently.

The issue I'm having with msgspec.Struct is that I have another class that inherits from two parent classes. And if the parent classes are type(msgspec.Struct) instead of dataclass the multiple inheritance doesn't work.

As the question didn't specifically say that, dataclass is required, I've added that as a separate answer, as this would be the intended way to code this if anyone wishes to copy it in the future.
